# How can i add button in menu (In Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add "button" to menu in my code, but the button is not working, i think i am doing something wrong, please correct me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


        <item
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"  />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_near"  />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"  />
        <Button 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_money"
            android:id="@+id/btn_remove_ads" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_review"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"  />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_share"  />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_email"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"  />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Use `app:actionViewClass` property and set it to `Button`

Answer (score 0):

You must set width and height. The button should be red underlined in Android Studio and usually tells you whats wrong, when you click the red bulb.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/whatever"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant add a Button in menu.xml, you must add a < Item> and change his icon, and handle the click in onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_1:
        TODO()
        return true;
    case R.id.nav_2:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[See more - Android Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)